# Box-sizing: border-box is causing an error on a JS fixed position sidebar, on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some javascript that applies a fixed class to my sidebar, so when you scroll, the menu stays with you. Stackoverflow has this with the similar questions sidebar.

```
    $(function() {      
    var top = $('.side-menu').offset().top - parseFloat($('.side-menu').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
      // what the y position of the scroll is
      var y = $(this).scrollTop();

      // whether that's below the form

      if (y >= top) {

        // if so, ad the fixed class
        $('.side-menu').addClass('fixed');
        $('body').addClass('fixed-sidebar');

      } else {
        // otherwise remove it
        $('.side-menu').removeClass('fixed');
        $('body').removeClass('fixed-sidebar');
      }
    });
});
```

In my CSS I have `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` which is causing the else to fire off and the page jumps. When I removed the box-sizing, the fixed menu works as desired.

**My question is**

- Is there another way to achieve what i'm trying to do?
- Is there a way to unset the `box-sizing` property?

**EDIT**

User this link for a demo: Resize the browser window at various heights and you'll see the issue. http://dev.danielcgold.com/fixed-menu.html

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?  You can always override the box-sizing property on the element that is causing you grief.

Comment: Is there something like a box-sizing: none?

Comment: @Dan No box-sizing merely changes the way the browser calculates padding and border relative to the width and height.  Here is some more info on box-sizing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: @Jrod I could reproduce with a fiddle so I create a quick test page. http://dev.danielcgold.com/fixed-menu.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always do `(selector) { box-sizing: content-box }` of course. (That will "unset" your `box-sizing`...)